# Copy all files when file count equals 10

Tags: powershell

I run below `PS` script and it works:

```
[int]$i = 0
while ($i -lt 10)
{
    ## File rename to adopt FH file naming conventions
    $FileToCopy = ($txml+"xmlperf_"+$arrDates[$i]+".xml")
    $datepart_ymd = '{0:yyMMdd}' -f ([datetime]::ParseExact($arrDates[$i], "MMddyy", $null))
    $FileNewName = ($txml+"xmlperf_002_"+$datepart_ymd+".xml")
    if (Test-Path $FileToCopy) {Rename-Item $FileToCopy $FileNewName -Force}
    $TimeNow = GetTimeNow -DateFormat "MMddyy HH:mm:ss"
    if (Test-Path $FileNewName)
    {
        try
        {
            Copy-Item $FileNewName $fout -Force -ErrorAction Stop
            $arrResults += New-Object Psobject -property
                @{
                    Time = get-date -Format o;
                    Task = ("Copy "+$FileNewName+" to FTP");
                    Status = "Success"; Details = "";
                    VisualCronJobName = 'FH_and_Valto_TWR_Performance_and_Performance_Security_Extract';
                    VisualCronTaskName = 'FH_TWR_Extracts_Performance';
                    DurationSec = $arrReturnResults.ExecTime;
                    CopyNumber = $CopyNumber;
                    IsTest = $Test
                }
        }
        catch
        {
            $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
            $arrResults += New-Object Psobject -property
                @{
                    Time = get-date -Format o;
                    Task = ("Copy "+$FileNewName+" to FTP");
                    Status = "Failed";
                    Details = $ErrorMessage;
                    VisualCronJobName = 'FH_and_Valto_TWR_Performance_and_Performance_Security_Extract';
                    VisualCronTaskName = 'FH_TWR_Extracts_Performance';
                    DurationSec = $arrReturnResults.ExecTime;
                    CopyNumber = $CopyNumber;
                    IsTest = $Test
                }
            $SmtpTo = $SmtpTo + $SmtpClient 
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $arrResults += New-Object Psobject -property
            @{
                Time = $TimeNow.TimeNow;
                Task = ("Copy "+$FileNewName+" to FTP");
                Status = "Failed";
                Details = "File not found";
                VisualCronJobName = 'FH_and_Valto_TWR_Performance_and_Performance_Security_Extract';
                VisualCronTaskName = 'FH_TWR_Extracts_Performance';
                DurationSec = $arrReturnResults.ExecTime;
                CopyNumber = $CopyNumber;
                IsTest = $Test
            }
        $SmtpTo = $SmtpTo + $SmtpClient 
    }
    $i++
}
```

So, this is what happens:

> 2023-06-19T07:18:13.9288478+02:00 Copy
> \vStoMhApp29-3\APX$\xml\xmlperf_002_230618.xml to FTP
> Success         2023-06-19T07:18:15.9457940+02:00 Copy
> \vStoMhApp29-3\APX$\xml\xmlperf_002_230617.xml to FTP
> Success         2023-06-19T07:18:17.9522785+02:00 Copy
> \vStoMhApp29-3\APX$\xml\xmlperf_002_230616.xml to FTP
> Success         2023-06-19T07:18:19.8900452+02:00 Copy
> \vStoMhApp29-3\APX$\xml\xmlperf_002_230615.xml to FTP
> Success         2023-06-19T07:18:21.8641485+02:00 Copy
> \vStoMhApp29-3\APX$\xml\xmlperf_002_230614.xml to FTP
> Success         2023-06-19T07:18:23.8923999+02:00 Copy
> \vStoMhApp29-3\APX$\xml\xmlperf_002_230613.xml to FTP
> Success         2023-06-19T07:18:25.8401134+02:00 Copy
> \vStoMhApp29-3\APX$\xml\xmlperf_002_230612.xml to FTP
> Success         2023-06-19T07:18:27.8985238+02:00 Copy
> \vStoMhApp29-3\APX$\xml\xmlperf_002_230611.xml to FTP
> Success         2023-06-19T07:18:29.9659928+02:00 Copy
> \vStoMhApp29-3\APX$\xml\xmlperf_002_230610.xml to FTP
> Success         2023-06-19T07:18:32.0473052+02:00 Copy
> \vStoMhApp29-3\APX$\xml\xmlperf_002_230609.xml to FTP
> Success

---

However, I want to copy files only when there are all 10 files in the path, so I change this to:

```
[int]$i = 10
while ($i -eq 10)
{
    ............
    $i++
}
```

I get following error:

> Failed  Exception calling "ParseExact"
> with "3" argument(s): "String
> was not recognized as a valid
> DateTime."

Comment: Check the value of: `$arrDates[10]`. Since `$i -lt 10`, `$i` is never 10.

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: This is the full code